# Running Django makemigrations Docker container

Tags: django, docker, django-migrations

I have two Docker containers, one for MySQL and one for Django. I modify a model that requires a migration, and therefore the need to run `makemigrations`: what do I do such that I end up with a 000X_stuff.py file on my local drive that, when I fire up the Django container and it runs the migration action, the migration occurs?

The only option that comes to mind is to run `docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME python ./manage.py makemigrations APP_NAME`. Two problems with this:

1. It only works the first time. Successive reruns of `makemigrations` claim there are no changes. The only way to overcome this is to drop the table and the appropriate row in the migrations table.
2. If any Python migration files are generated, they are generated within the container. I would have to copy them manually from container to host if I want to commit them.

Comment: This is on your local dev environment? Are you syncing your code changes to the container via a mounted volume or rebuilding the container every time? A volume should copy the changes back to your local filesystem

Comment: Ah, thank you, making the migrations directory a mountable volume was what I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Iain's answer, I had to add a simple volume to my docker-compose file to make the files accessible locally:

```
volumes:
      - ./backend/server/project/migrations:/app/backend/server/project/migrations
```